# Spring JDBC call for SQL Server function returning incorrect data

Tags: sql-server, java-8, spring-jdbc, sql-function

At first it looks like a silly question from a fairly new person, however my observations are very very strange. It may be difficult to answer because of unavailability of data and complete code. I'm looking for people who have faced similar issues and solution if possible.

**Java and SQL codes:**
I have a SQL Query which looks like below as java String for jdbcTemplate:

```
SELECT patientid, visitid, visitid1, visitid2, admitdate1, admitdate2, dischargedate1, dischargedate2, transfertype, sourcesystemuniqueidentifier FROM fn_XXXX_2017(?,?)
```

Here fn_XXXX_2017 is a SQL Server function that accepts two parameters of type `BIGINT` and definition is as below:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_XXXX_2017]
( @id1 BIGINT ,@id2 BIGINT )
RETURNS TABLE 
as
return
(
-- really big joins and unions
)
```

**Spring jdbc call from java is as below:**

```
long startRowNum = 111;
long endRowNum = 111;
List<Pojo> queryResult = this.jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new Object[]{startRowNum, endRowNum}, new MapperForPojo());
```

**Observations and Cases:**
When i execute the SQL Query directly into SQL Server Management Studio I get below results

[image]

**Now we come to java to see the concern**

**Case 1** (Which works correct)
we use SQL Query for jdbcTemplate as:

```
SELECT patientid, visitid, visitid1, visitid2, admitdate1, admitdate2, dischargedate1, dischargedate2, transfertype, sourcesystemuniqueidentifier FROM fn_XXXX_2017(?,?)
```

Please notice there is no space in **(?,?)**

**Case 2** (Which gives incorrect result)
we use SQL Query for jdbcTemplate as:

```
SELECT patientid, visitid, visitid1, visitid2, admitdate1, admitdate2, dischargedate1, dischargedate2, transfertype, sourcesystemuniqueidentifier FROM fn_XXXX_2017(?, ?)
```

Please notice the **space** before second question mark as **(?,*[space here]*?)**

In case two (Which doesn't work) i see data in eclipse as below:
[image]

This works unreliably when we add/remove spaces from the SQL Query String in java.

**Tried below things to find the reason:**

1. Looked into SQL Server profiler to make sure parameter values and
   query is correct (Found it to be correct)
2. Debugged Spring java
   Mappers to check if values are set correct (found it to be correct)
3. Debugged sqljdbc jar's by enabling
   `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.level=FINEST`. (Even here i see that
   values are not correct in the generated console logs)
4. `this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query)`. here i hardcoded the
   parameter values and found that it returns correct data.
5. Tried using latest version of microsofts sql jdbc driver sqljdbc42.jar

**Confusion and question:**

What may be wrong that `this.jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[]{param1, param2}, Mapper())` version of jdbcTemplate is returning correct data only when i make removed spaces from sql query (just before last ? for parameter)?

**Version information**

1. Java Version:

   java version "1.8.0_92"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
2. SQL Server Version:

   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
       Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
       Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )
3. SQL JDBC jar: sqljdbc4-42.jar
4. Eclipse version: Neon and Mars
5. OS: Windows 10
6. Spring version 4.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: The space between arguments in the query string shouldn't matter. Try adding some trace logging to see what is actually passed in (something like: `logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc=TRACE`). You might also try eliminating the row mapper by testing with one of the `queryForList` methods.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for response. I got the idea after testing SQL Function with different parameters and ranges and It was SQL Function to blame to. However I'm still stumped on how creating spaces in query string was affecting the result.